# Proof: Number theory: Prove that if $n$ is composite, then the least $b$ such that $n$ is not $b$-pseudoprime is prime.

Tags: number-theory

I'm looking to prove this, but not too sure how:

If $n$ is composite, then the least $b$ such that $n$ is not $b$-psp is prime.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $b$ be the minimum such element and assume it is not prime.Then $b=cd$ and $b^{n-1}\not\equiv 1 \bmod n$ . Then $b^{n-1}=c^{n-1}d^{n-1}\not \equiv 1$. So one of $b^{n-1}$ and $c^{n-1}$ is not $1\bmod n$. Contradicting the minimality of $b$.

Comment: Beautifully concise.  Thanks Mr. The Emperor of Ice Cream.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know that result until now.

Comment: Now I need to ask - figuring this out, what methods did you first try? I'm trying to become proficient with number theory (this is my first course) but I'm finding the proof portion of it to be rather daunting.  Any advice?  Thanks!

Comment: I guess I got a little lucky. I initially conjectured that if $n$ is not a $b$-pseudoprime then any divisor $d$ of $b$ is going to satisfy that $n$ is not a $d$-pseudoprime, but this turned out to be false. So I figured out that at least one of $d$ and $b/d$ must satisfy that.